# ROS-Industrial support for Kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was a little bit shocked when I saw that the ROS-I installation page suggests installation with/on Hydro: http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install.

Now, does anyone have experience with ROS-I running with Kinetic?
Through how much pain would I need to go through?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254327/ros-industrial-support-for-kinetic/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2017-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a 'known issue': [ros-industrial/ros_industrial_issues#40](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_industrial_issues/issues/40). The tutorial is outdated (and technically, it does not really suggests to install Hydro: it documents how to install various ROS-Industrial packages *on* ROS Hydro. But it is outdated in any case. Edit: I've just updated the page to at least make *that* more clear).

> Now, does anyone have experience with ROS-I running with Kinetic? Through how much pain would I need to go through?

That will completely depend on what packages you'd like to use. Without knowing that, I can only tell you that almost all packages will build from sources in a Catkin workspace, they just haven't all been released.

If you can update your question and include which packages you need, I can provide more detailed instructions if needed.

---

Edit:

> So I would like to use the universal_robot, ur_modern_driver, ur_modern_driver, moveit, basically anything that I need to do ik, calculate trajectories and planning. I think the first three are little problematic.

you list `ur_modern_driver` twice, but:

- moveit has been released for Kinetic, so that is just an `apt-get` away (note btw that MoveIt is not a ROS-Industrial package)
- `universal_robot` has a `kinetic-devel` branch and is being used by many people on Kinetic already

As for `ur_modern_driver`: there is currently no development targetting Kinetic, but incompatibilities are mostly confined to the `ros_control` parts. If you don't need those, you should be able to compile and run everything. If you need / want the `hardware_interface`, there is at least one fork that addressed the incompatibilities. See [ur_modern_driver#58](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues/58) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2017-02-10**:
Thanks! So I would like to use the universal_robot, ur_modern_driver, ur_modern_driver, moveit, basically anything that I need to do ik, calculate trajectories and planning. I think the first three are little problematic.

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2017-02-14**:
Great thank you!